# Explicit solution to the laplacian exterior domain with point source.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplacian

Consider $\Omega = \mathbb{R}^3 \setminus B(0,a)$ an exterior domain and $b \in \Omega$. I want to find the explicit solution of the following laplacian problem

\begin{aligned}
-  \Delta u = \alpha\delta(x-b) \text{ in } \Omega\\
u = 0 \text{ on } \partial \Omega\\
u(x) \underset{|x| \rightarrow +\infty}{\longrightarrow} 0
\end{aligned}

On the whole domain $\mathbb{R}^3$, $-  \Delta u = \alpha\delta(x-b)$ would be easy to solve using the fundamental solution. However this is not possible here.

I'm looking for techniques or references to solve this problem. I was maybe thinking of something like boundary integral representation and layer potential techniques.

Any help or advice are welcomed !

Comment: Unless I misunderstand, this is the classic 'grounded sphere near point charge' problem which may be solved using the method of images

Comment: Hello @Sal, thanks a lot for your comment. Indeed, my problem is exactly this one, I'm going to look a bit on my own but do you have references to recommend ? Also, I'm interested in the same problem but in fluid mechanics with the Stokes equation, which would be "immobile sphere near point force". Do you think the method of images would work for this Stokes problem (I will probably ask a second question for it though) ?

Comment: No problem! You can look in eg Jackson's *Classical electrodynamics* for the image problem (or any number of online lecture notes). I *think* an analogous method should work for your Stokes problem (haven't tried yet though)